# How do I reference previous state in lodash's filter method?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, lodash

```
const [panelRight, setPanelRight] = useState(sample(filter(menu, (el) => el !== panelLeft)));

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {

    const menuCategory = filter(menu, (el) => el !== panelLeft && el !== panelRight);

    setPanelRight(sample(menuCategory));

   }, 10000);
```

Currently panelRight is being set to the same random menu element every time the the setInterval is called. I think this might be because I need to reference the previous state in the filter method, but how?

Comment: You could use `useRef()` to store previous values and update the ref as the state updates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code lacks details, we dont know what is in your useEffect `deps` so lets assume and guess. Provide more details next time, please.

Lets assume your useEffect has an empty `[]` dependencies array and called only once on the first render.

So the issue - setInterval will always hold the value it had initially when the setInterval callback (closure) was defined. Values from the first render.

And here is what you should do:

```
// Insert that before or after your setStates section
const panelRightRef = React.useRef();
const panelLeftRef = React.useRef();

// That will update ref variables
useEffect(() => {panelRightRef.current = panelRight}, [panelRight]);
useEffect(() => {panelLeftRef.current = panelLeft}, [panelLeft]);

useEffect(() => {
    const interval = setInterval(() => {
        // if menu is also a State variable and is not immutable - you should add useRef() for it
        const menuCategory = filter(menu, (el) => el !== panelLeftRef.current && el !== panelRightRef.current);
        setPanelRight(sample(menuCategory));
    }, 10000);

    // that will be called on depsarray changes or when component is destroyed
    return () => clearInterval(interval);
}, []);
```